# How to read a matrix from txt file to template matrix?

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a template matrix and I dont know how to read my "matrix1" txt file.How do I need to define the "open1" method?Here is my class and my file.
In the file the first two numbers are the row and the column of the matrix.

```
template <class T = double>
     class Matrix
     {
     private:
         unsigned row;
         unsigned column;
         T ** matrix;
         template<class OUTP>
             friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrix<OUTP>&);
         template<class INP>
         friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&,  Matrix<INP>&);

     public:

         Matrix(unsigned = 0, unsigned = 0);
         ~Matrix();
         Matrix(const Matrix & other);
         void setMatrixElement(unsigned, unsigned, T);
         void delMatrix();
         T getElement(unsigned = 0, unsigned = 0);
         unsigned getRow()const { return row; }
         unsigned getColumn()const { return column; }

         bool open1();
     };
```

Here is my file

```
 3 3
26.062000 16.600000 24.900000 49.800000 0.000000 1.000000 2.000000 
4.000000 5.000000
```

EDIT:

This is my new code but with this I can't build solution and I don't know how to handle the error:Exception thrown: read access violation.
this->matrix was 0x1110112."

```
 template <class T>
bool Matrix<T> ::open1()


{   
ifstream myfile("matrix1.txt");

if (!myfile)
{
    cout << "Error with fileopening" << endl;

    return false;

}
myfile >> row;
myfile >> column;
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < column; i++)
    {
        myfile >> matrix[i][j];
    }
}




myfile.close();                     
return true;
```

}}

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: *I wrote it as an answer* – if you want to make additions to your question edit your question. answers are for answers.

Comment: *Here is my file* – whats the numbers in the different lines supposed to mean?

Comment: the elements of the matrix

Comment: `Matrix<T> M;` has no business being in that `open1` function. Remove it and replace all`M.anything` in that function with just `anything`.

Answer (score 0):

[`<fstream>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/fstream) will be your friend:

Instead of working with file pointers,  you simply work with streams:

```
ifstream ifs("matrix1.txt");     // istream is "r"
```

You can check if the stream has a problem

```
if (!ifs) {
    // .. ouch 
}
```

Reading data is as simple as

```
ifs >> row >> column;
```

or

```
ifs >> M.matrix[j][g];
```

C++ infers the type of the data you want to read  so you don't need to use the manual error prone `"%d"` or `"%lf"` that you need in `scanf()`.

In addition, it's much more powerful, since it would always call the right overload of the stream extractor if you would instantiate your matrix with `T` being something else than a `double`. For example with `Matrix<std::complex<double>>` you could read with the same templated code a file like:

```
2 2
(1.0,1.0) 2.0  
(2.5,4) (2.0,1.0)
```

where `(2.0,1.0)` is the standard representation of a complex with 2.0 as real part and 1.0 as imaginary part.

Comment: @jacky great! if it solves the issue and it helped, don’t forget to accept the answer ;-)

Comment: But to build I also  would like  to know how to handle exceptions:/